# How to query an input in Python without outputting a new line

Tags: python, input, python-3.x, newline

The title describes the question pretty much.

Comment: Not to the extent you think it does.  Can you show some code please.

Comment: Please provide sample code and mention the language in the title or body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `input` function, which does the query, does not emit a newline:

```
>>> input('tell me: ')
tell me: what?
'what?'
>>>
```

as you see, the prompt is output without any newline, and what the user types after that appears on the same line as the prompt.  Of course, the *user* is also typing a newline, and (like everything else the user types), **that** newline is echoed (so further results are on following lines).  Is that your problem?

If so, then you need to switch to platform-specific approaches, such as [curses](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/curses.html?highlight=ncurses) on just about any machine except Windows, and [msvcrt](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/msvcrt.html?highlight=msvcrt#module-msvcrt) on Windows (or, you could look for a `curses` port on Windows, but I don't know if there's one for Python 3).  The two modules are very different, and you haven't clarified your platform (or your exact needs -- my previous paragraph is an attempt at an educated guess;-), so I'll just wait for you to clarify needs and platforms rather than launching into long essays that may not prove helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you use raw_input it does not insert a new line automatically.

```
>>> name = raw_input ("What...is your name? ") 
What...is your name? Arthur, King of the Britons!
```

Comment: Ahh, I read the title, the body, then went ahead with very little information. I did not read the tags in detail.

Comment: for any newbie reading along, that means raw_input gone in 3.0, and input in 3.0 no longer has the horrific surprise that it doesn't do exactly what most of the uninitiated people thought it did.