# How to query an input in Python without outputting a new line (cont.)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I already posted this, but here is the exact code:

> ```
> x1 = input("")
> x2 = input("-")
> x3 = input("-")
> x4 = input("-")
> ```

So, how would I do it so that there are no spaces between the first input and the next "-"?

Example:

> 1234-5678-9101-1121

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The answers to your prior version of your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982964/how-to-query-an-input-in-python-without-outputting-a-new-line also say that  they can't guess your intentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> x1, x2, x3, x4 = raw_input("Input number as xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx").split('-')
```

If you're using Python version 3.x, replace `rawinput` with `input`.

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but you could use [terminal escape sequences](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm#cursor) to delete the newline created by the user ending input between each successive call of input().

The appropriate sequences of escapes would be `<Esc>[2K` to erase the current line, and then possibly `<Esc>[nC` to move forwards n characters where n is calculated by retrieving the length of the string that the last input() call returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code in [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user) to read stdin character by character (basically reading it in unbuffered mode so that the user doesn't have to type enter before you can see the input).